# rails 3.2 and mercury editor cant find object through edit/ route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, mercury-editor

My `routes.rb`:

```
DigitalizmAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
  ## Admin routes
  namespace :mercury do
    resources :images
  end
  mount Mercury::Engine => '/'

  devise_for :admins #, :skip => [:registrations, :passwords]
  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "admin#dashboard"

    resources :categories do
      member { post :mercury_update }
    end
    resources :posts do
      member { post :mercury_update }
    end
    resources :pages do
      member { post :mercury_update }
    end
  end

  ## Regular routes
  root to: "welcome#index"

  get 'posts/*categories_uri/:post_uri' => "posts#show"
  get 'categories/*categories_uri' => "categories#show"

  # here is the regular page route
  get 'page/:uri' => "pages#show", as: :page
  get 'sitemap/*categories_uri' => 'sitemap#show'
  get 'sitemap' => 'sitemap#index'

  ## Catch all unexisted routes
  match "*path", to: "application#render_404", via: :all
end
```

Here is how I construct link to edit in view:

```
= link_to "Edit", "/editor" + page_path(item)
```

On the route `host/page/:slug` I can see the page, but when Im on route `host/edit/page/:slug`
I have 404 error.

---

In the browser console I can see error:
`GET http://host/page/:slug?mercury_frame=true&_=1388132782182 404 (Not Found)`
But all mercury-editor's js files have been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code in the view

```
<%= link_to "Edit",  "/editor" + admin_page_path(item), id: "edit_link", data: { save_url: mercury_update_admin_page_path(item) } %>
```

And place this code to the end of mercury.js

```
onload: function() {
//Mercury.PageEditor.prototype.iframeSrc = function(url) { return '/testing'; }
Mercury.on('ready', function() {
  var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
  Mercury.saveUrl = link.data('save_url');
  link.hide();
});

Mercury.on('saved', function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\/editor\//i, '/');
});
```

}

Then navigate to `http://host/editor/admin/pages/:slug`